# What is meant by disturbing in this context

Tags: meaning, verbs, adjectives, definition

My girlfriend and I do not agree on the meaning of the following:

"It's disturbing"

I say that it could mean two things:

- it is interrupting
- it is unsettling

But she thinks it can only mean

- It is unsettling

What do you guys think? Can it be a verb in the sentence or not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> It's disturbing.

This is a complete sentence using the participial adjective *disturbing*, meaning (in your words) "it is unsettling".

It cannot be the verb *disturb* meaning "interrupt" because [this sense of the verb is **transitive**](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/disturb) and requires a direct object:

> It's disturbing **me**.

Here, *me* is the direct object of *disturbing*, so it's possible for it to have the "interrupt" meaning.  But without the direct object, it's not possible.

Comment: +++ A marvelously elegant explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct to this extent: the **verb** *disturb* has a range of literal and figurative meanings:

- You can “disturb” someone's work or routine, or any process or flow, and thus interrupt it.
- You can “disturb” someone's mental or emotional state and thus worry or unsettle them.
- You  can “disturb” an arrangement or disposition by moving components.

Any of these senses may be expressed with *disturbing*, the present participle, as the head of a non-finite clause or as a component of a progressive (continuative) construction.

> Telephone calls are a nuisance, disrupting my thought and disturbing my work.
>   What I heard about his lack of progress was disturbing me.
>   I wish the cleaners would stop disturbing my papers.

But your girlfriend is also correct, to this extent. In the sentence *It's disturbing* the word disturbing does not act as a verb or component of a verb construction. It acts merely as an **adjective**—linguists call this a *deverbal*, an ‘un-verbed’ verbform. And as an adjective, *disturbing* has **only** the sense of “mentally or emotionally unsettling”. A *disturbing* telephone call, for instance, is one in which unsettling facts or attitudes are communicated, not one which interrupts your routine.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are feeling unsettled because of her disturbing argument. This verb ***disturb*** is very tricky to us learners, because when we say *"It is disturbing"*, it is disturbingly not a verb anymore; *disturbing* now becomes an adjective. So grammatically speaking, your girlfriend is at an advantage because *interrupting* cannot be used as an adjective, while both *disturbing* and *unsettling* can, as @snailplane explained. But if she said that the *unsettling* in *"It's unsettling"* is a verb, then you can say that she was wrong too. Because, in your example sentences, **neither *disturbing* nor *unsettling* is a verb**.

Your advantage is perhaps the face that both ***interrupt*** and ***unsettle*** are synonyms of *disturb*, and they are the synonyms in different senses, as @StoneyB explained. A *disturbing* movie could give me an ***unsettled*** feeling. However, if someone interrupted me, it would be more likely that I would feel that they were *disturbing me* rather than *unsettling me*. On the other hand, if someone *keeps disturbing* me, I probably will think that they are so *annoying* rather than *unsettling*. And, before I break into a conversation, I might ask *"Am I interrupting (something/anything)?"* first, because I know that I might **disturb** them by **interrupting** their conversation.

One last note, as I have often been reminded, each word exists for good reason. Even synonyms cannot always replace each other. And, context is the king.